# What is causing syntax error in arcpy NetCDF Raster script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, netcdf

I'm trying to save the raster layer in the stand-alone python GUI but I keep getting a syntax error.

I'm using the code from [Save To Layer File (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000070000000). 
And the error that shows up is: the LA MESA part of below:

```
in_features = "spain_1901_1.shp"
out_layer0 = "spain_1901_1"
where_clause = '"NAME" = 'LA MESA''
workspace = "C:/output"
```

now I've replaced their fill in things from the website with what I need but I keep getting an error saying that LA MESA isn't the correct syntax even when I replace it with my own name.

please help!

EDIT: Here's the entire code:

```
#MAKE RASTER FILE
# Import system modules
import arcpy


# Set local variables
inNetCDFFile = "C:/Users/ESS/Desktop/temp/tmpy1901m01.nc"
variable = "tmp"
XDimension = "lon"
YDimension = "lat"
outRasterLayer = "C:/Users/ESS/Desktop/out/spain_1901_1.shp"
bandDimmension = ""
dimensionValues = ""
valueSelectionMethod = ""

# Execute MakeNetCDFRasterLayer
arcpy.MakeNetCDFRasterLayer_md(inNetCDFFile, variable, XDimension, YDimension, outRasterLayer, bandDimmension, dimensionValues, valueSelectionMethod)

#SAVE IT!!!!!!
# Name: SaveToLayerFile_Example2.py
# Description: Saves an inMemory layer to a file on disk
# Author: ESRI

# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set workspace
env.workspace = "C:/Users/ESS/Desktop/out"

# Set local variables
in_layer = "spain_1901_1"
out_layer = "spain_1901_1.lyr"

#MakeFeatureLayer variables
in_features = "spain_1901_1.shp"
out_layer0 = "spain_1901_1"
where_clause = '"NAME" = \'LA MESA\''
workspace = "C:/Users/ESS/Desktop/out"

try:
    # Execute MakeFeatureLayer
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features, out_layer0, where_clause, workspace)

    # Execute SaveToLayerFile
    arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(in_layer, out_layer, "ABSOLUTE")
except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages()

##THE CALCULATIONS  
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "C:/Users/ESS/Desktop/out"

# Set local variables
inZoneData = "es2001.shp"
zoneField = "FIDS"
inValueRaster = "spain_1901_1"
outTable = "spain_1901_1_data.dbf"


# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Execute ZonalStatisticsAsTable
outZSaT = ZonalStatisticsAsTable(inZoneData, zoneField, inValueRaster, 
                                 outTable, "NODATA", "ALL")
```

Comment: I answered this too quickly.  Since that syntax is used in the sample it would work here as well.  We need to have more of your script to see if there is something else going on.  It might be related to the fact that you are saving a raster layer.  This sample was set up for a feature layer and there may be some differences in the syntax necessary.  Please post the rest of your script.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the LA MESA portion with backslashes. Like so, `'"NAME" = \'LA MESA\''` Single quotes are reserved characters in Python and must be escaped so that the interpreter knows that you wish for them to be regarded as a string. Check this link on the Python documentation: http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. Thanks though!

Comment: I'll defer to @Get-Spatial for this then, as he correctly noted the trouble is likely somewhere more severe than the query string. My above should resolve any string escaping issues, however.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are having a single vs. double quotes issue.  I'm pretty sure you cannot have single quotes within other single quotes.

Try this:

```
in_features = "spain_1901_1.shp"
out_layer0 = "spain_1901_1"
where_clause = "'NAME' = 'LA MESA'"
workspace = "C:/output"
```

Edit --------------

The quote issue above is probably a minor problem.
You stated that you are exporting a `Raster`.  This however, doesn't work for the details you have in the script provided.  You cannot have a `Raster` Layer that is saved as a `Shapefile`.  You need to first make sure the type of features you are exporting and what you are exporting to.
The other issue is that the `Where` clause is specifying a field of title `Name` in the shapefile where the values are equal to **La Mesa**.  Unless you have specifically created an attribute table for your `Raster`, the only contents you would be able to select for would be a field named `Value`, and the contents would be **Integer** values, not text.

As I said in my comment above, please provide more detail and I'll edit this answer as more info is available.

Edit 2 -----------------
Edit 3 -----------------

Simplicity is the answer here.  One thing that is often confusing in ArcGIS is when you have to actually save a layer to disk, thus saving the actual Raster Dataset, or when you may use the Raster Layer as the input to a new function.  Based on the script you added above, it looks like a number of the functions may actually be left out.

The first step is to [Make a NetCDF Raster Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004300000006000000.htm)

The output of this is a `Raster Layer`, which is essentially the ArcGIS Raster object properties with your `NetCDF Layer` as the source.
This step negates the need for a couple of steps in your original script, which are as follows:

- [Make Feature Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Make_Feature_Layer/00170000006p000000/) - This is not necessary for 2 reasons.  The first is that it is the wrong function.  Since you are dealing with a Raster, you would use the [Make Raster Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Make_Raster_Layer/00170000006t000000/).  `Feature Layers` deal with vector data, whereas `Raster Layers` deal with grid based data, and each has specific unique properties.  The 2nd reason it is not necessary is that the `Make NetCDF Raster Layer` function outputs the same type of layer as this function would.
- [Save Layer File](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Save_To_Layer_File/001700000070000000/) - This simply saves a `.lyr` file to disk, thus letting you bring up the Raster again with the same properties saved.  It does not actually create a new Raster Dataset.  That would be accomplished with a different function, which may be an option down below.

As I mentioned above, it is sometimes hard to determine when you can work with a `Raster Layer` as an input, or when you need to actually reference a `Raster Dataset` that is saved to disk.  For that reason, I will include two different versions of the script.  The 2nd version will include the intermediate step of saving the NetCDF Raster to a `.tif` on disk, and then referencing that in the `Zonal Statistics` function.

Version #1:

```
#MAKE RASTER FILE
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy import sa

# Set Local variables
inNetCDFFile = "C:/Users/ESS/Desktop/temp/tmpy1901m01.nc"
variable = "tmp"
XDimension = "lon"
YDimension = "lat"
outRasterLayer = "C:/Users/ESS/Desktop/out/spain_1901_1"
bandDimmension = ""
dimensionValues = ""
valueSelectionMethod = ""

# Execute MakeNetCDFRasterLayer
arcpy.MakeNetCDFRasterLayer_md(inNetCDFFile, variable, XDimension, YDimension, outRasterLayer, bandDimmension, dimensionValues, valueSelectionMethod)

#Perform Spatial Statistics calculations using Spatial Analyst
# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "C:/Users/ESS/Desktop/out"

# Set local variables
inZoneData = "es2001.shp"
zoneField = "FIDS"
inValueRaster = outRasterLayer
outTable = "spain_1901_1_data.dbf"


# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Execute ZonalStatisticsAsTable
outZSaT = ZonalStatisticsAsTable(inZoneData, zoneField, inValueRaster, 
                                 outTable, "NODATA", "ALL")
```

A couple of important points to note:  I have removed the references to saving a `.shp` file from your output Raster in the NetCDF Raster function.  This is because the [Shapefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) format is a `vector` format and would likely generate an error upon running.  Also, I have simply passed through the variable for the layer name of the output from the first function, to the variable for the input of the 2nd function.

In case the above doesn't work because the Zonal Statistics script requires an actual Raster dataset as input, I am including another version where the NetCDF Raster Layer output is saved to a Raster `.tif` file using the [Raster Copy](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Copy_Raster/001700000094000000/) function.

Version 2:

```
#MAKE RASTER FILE
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy import sa

# Set Local variables
inNetCDFFile = "C:/Users/ESS/Desktop/temp/tmpy1901m01.nc"
variable = "tmp"
XDimension = "lon"
YDimension = "lat"
outRasterLayer = "C:/Users/ESS/Desktop/out/spain_1901_1"
bandDimmension = ""
dimensionValues = ""
valueSelectionMethod = ""

# Execute MakeNetCDFRasterLayer
arcpy.MakeNetCDFRasterLayer_md(inNetCDFFile, variable, XDimension, YDimension, outRasterLayer, bandDimmension, dimensionValues, valueSelectionMethod)

#Save Raster Layer to disk as .tif file

inrasterlayer = outRasterLayer
outRastertif = "C:/Users/ESS/Desktop/out/spain_1901_1.tif"

try:
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(inrasterlayer,outRastertif)
except:
    print "Copy Raster example failed."
    print arcpy.GetMessages()

#Perform Spatial Statistics calculations using Spatial Analyst
# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "C:/Users/ESS/Desktop/out"

# Set local variables
inZoneData = "es2001.shp"
zoneField = "FIDS"
inValueRaster = "spain_1901_1.tif"
outTable = "spain_1901_1_data.dbf"


# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Execute ZonalStatisticsAsTable
outZSaT = sa.ZonalStatisticsAsTable(inZoneData, zoneField, inValueRaster, 
                                 outTable, "NODATA", "ALL")
```

Hopefully this will help, let me know if there are still problems.

Comment: I'm really new at ArcGIS, but I have had some experience with python. My goal is to import a shp file, then import weather data in a .nc file. Do some computations with that file. Save it, then convert it to a .csv

Comment: @user10877 - I edited my answer to incorporate the code you included.  Hopefully it will shed some light.

Comment: Executing: MakeRasterLayer spain_1901_1 spain_1901_1 # # #
Start Time: Wed Oct 10 23:19:18 2012
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000865: Input raster: spain_1901_1 does not exist.
Failed to execute (MakeRasterLayer).
Failed at Wed Oct 10 23:19:19 2012 (Elapsed Time: 1.00 seconds)

Comment: Here,  in_raster and out_raslayer names are same. Those should be different.


May be this will be helpful:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006t000000

Comment: @user10877 - I updated my answer. Please take a look and see if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
where_clause = " NAME = 'LA MESA' "
```

`NAME` is a field name, not a string.

The `WHERE` clause `'NAME' = 'LA MESA'` will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
where_clause = "\"Name\" = 'LA MESA'"
```

Or,

```
where_clause = "Name = 'LA MESA'"
```

Both should work, if the column "Name" is  present in the attribute table.